# Get non persistent field populated on select

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I use Doctrine with Symfony and I have the following simple Entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\Table()
*/
class Ads{

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var Photo
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="advertisement", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    *
    */
    private $photos;

    /**
    * @var string
    */
    private $defaultPhoto = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->photos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
    * Get id
    *
    * @return int
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getPhotos()
    {
        return $this->photos;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $photos
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPhotos($photos)
    {
        $this->photos = $photos;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDefaultPhoto()
    {
        if(count($this->getPhotos()) > 0){
            return $this->getPhotos()[0];
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

So the Entity is a simple one and also has a non persistent field `$defaultPhotos`.

My question is how, when I query `find` or `findAll` with doctrine in Symfony automatically triggers the `getDefaultPhoto` method and populate `$defaultPhoto` property? Now every time `defaultPhoto` is `null` when I query `find` or `findAll` in whole collection.

Is there an event to do that or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, you will not populate anything (`$defaultPhoto`) with a getter (`getDefaultPhoto`).
You can populate `defaultPhoto` property on the class' constructor, and then return `$this->defaultPhoto` instead of `null` on `getDefaultPhoto()` method.